# C++ modifying const pointer reference value

Tags: c++, pointers

I've encountered similar code piece today and it got me wondering. I did a little experiment myself as shown below.

Why does the first `stuff` function with shared pointer allow to modify the value while seconds one doesn't?

```
#include <memory>

void stuff(const std::shared_ptr<int> &var)
{
    *var = 5;
}

void stuff(const int* &var)
{
    *var = 5;
}

int main()
{
    auto a = std::make_shared<int>();
    stuff(a);

    int* b;
    stuff(b);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The rule of const is that the modifier is applied to type immediately to the left; unless there is no type, in which case it is applied immediately to the right. In the first case, the const is applied to the shared_ptr, but not the value pointed to. In the second case, the const is applied to int, not int*. Therefore, you’re not allowed to change the value. For the first case, use const shared_ptr<const int>&.

Comment: @Rish Please don't write answers in comments

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I believe this comment was written when the question was on code review. It's not appropriate to answer this question there.

Comment: @cigien That doesn't make it appropriate to answer in the comments instead. That is double-bad then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two types:

- `const std::shared_ptr<int>`
- `const int*` (aka `int const*`)

are fundamentally different:

- The first one is a `const` pointer to an `int`;
- The second one is a pointer to a `const int`.

The `shared_ptr` equivalent of the version that doesn't permit modification of the pointee would be `std::shared_ptr<const int>`.

The raw pointer equivalent of the version that *does* permit modification of the pointee would be `int* const`.

**Ability to modify the pointer, and ability to modify the pointed-to thing, are different things.**